# Error While sending mails using Java Mail in eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I tried to send a simple mail using Java in Eclipse. When I am trying to run the program a small window opened named ast jtree example. It has root followed by c1 c2 c3 and mail did not send.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SingleEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String to = "thamaraikani8@gmail.com";
          String from = "buddycoolrj@gmail.com"; 
          String host = "localhost";//or IP address  

         //Get the session object  
          Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
          properties.setProperty("mail.user", "buddycoolrj@gmail.com");
          properties.setProperty("mail.password", "tecknodel");
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);  
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  
         //compose the message  
          try{  
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
             message.setSubject("Ping");  
             message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");  

             // Send message  
             Transport.send(message);  
             System.out.println("message sent successfully....");  

          }catch (MessagingException mex) {mex.printStackTrace();}  
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a mail server running on localhost? Because that's where you're sending the mail to.

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with java and so could you please tell me about mail server.

Comment: Check @Manu's answer below, those seem to be the right configuration.

Comment: I have changed the code as Manu said. Still same problem exists

Comment: We need more details about the error (stack trace, line where it happens) to help you further.

Comment: I am not getting any error. When i run the program, nothing happens except that small window named AST jtree open.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using gmail ids as from & to address, You can use below gmail Server details to send email.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",  
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Comment: I have changed the code as below. Still same problem exists.

Comment: Try changing the port to 587.